# Spark metrics - Disable all metrics

Tags: apache-spark

I'm building a monitoring system for our Spark. I sent the metrics with spark's graphite sink. I want to have the ability to stop all the metrics dynamically. So that means I need to set it with `sc.set`.

How can I just disable all metrics in the spark configuration? Because I couldn't find something like `spark.metrics.enable` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way of disabling it. What I do is only set it if I want to monitor (per application).

```
sc.set("spark.metrics.conf.*.sink.graphite.class", "org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.GraphiteSink")
```